# Scientific notation in seaborn plot and pivot table

Tags: python, seaborn

I m trying to use seaborn plot to plot my usedcar data set and I m getting scientific notation in the x axis instead of the actual number. It affects the pivot data too. Please suggest a way to remove the scientific notation.

Code:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
sns.scatterplot(x='Price_in_Lac',y='Kilometers_Driven',hue='Location',data=df)
---------------------------------------------------------------
df_hm =df.pivot_table(index = 'Brand',columns ='Location',values ="Price_in_Lac",aggfunc=np.median)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
sns.heatmap(df_hm,   cmap='coolwarm',linewidths=.5, annot=True, ax=ax);
```

[image: Scatter plot]

[image: Pivot Table]

Answer (score 2):

For the `scatterplot` you can use `ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)` to remove the scientific notation and `....set_useOffset(False)`.

Here is an example using the penguins dataset with lengths converted to nanometers to get larger numbers:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
penguins["flipper_length_nm"] = penguins["flipper_length_mm"] * 1000000
penguins["bill_length_nm"] = penguins["bill_length_mm"] * 1000000
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='flipper_length_nm', y='bill_length_nm', hue='species', data=penguins)
ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

At the left with the original formatting, at the right with the scientific notation removed:
[image: removing scientific notation in scatterplot]

For the colorbar, you need to get access to its `ax`, for example using the last created one (`fig.axes[-1]`):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
penguins["flipper_length_nm"] = penguins["flipper_length_mm"] * 1000000
penguins["bill_length_nm"] = penguins["bill_length_mm"] * 1000000

df_hm = penguins.pivot_table(index='sex', columns='species', values="flipper_length_nm", aggfunc=np.median)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
sns.heatmap(df_hm, cmap='coolwarm', linewidths=.5, annot=True, ax=ax)
cbar_ax = fig.axes[-1]
cbar_ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
cbar_ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar with scientific notation removed]

PS: If you want a thousands separator, you can use `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))`.

As mentioned in the other answer, if you also want to change the format of the annotations, you can use `sns.heatmap(...,fmt='.0f')` (or `fmt=',.0f'` to get a thousands separator).

Comment: Adding format (fmt='.0f') works.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's `heatmap` has a `fmt` parameter that formats the annotations.

See the doc [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).

You can get rid of the scientific notation in the heatmap specifying `fmt='.2f'` or `fmt='.0f'`

```py
sns.heatmap(df_hm, cmap='coolwarm', linewidths=.5, annot=True, ax=ax, fmt='.2f');
```